# Calculate MD5 checksum for an image in C#

Tags: c#, .net, image, hash, md5

Code referenced in the StackOverflow question titled "Calclate MD5 checksum for a file" provides a simple way to get a checksum based on a file. This works, however through testing I have found that changing file metadata also causes the checksum to change. And I guess this makes sense, well, because a copy with different metadata is technically a different file. That code:

```
using (var md5 = MD5.Create())
{
    using (var stream = File.OpenRead(filename))
    {
        return md5.ComputeHash(stream);
    }
}
```

As images pass through various systems here at work, image metadata is added and changed for various reasons, which means a file checksum cannot be used to find duplicates among our systems.

What I need is a way to generate a checksum based on an image itself, not an image *file*.

My attempt to solve this problem has resulted in this code:

```
using (var md5 = MD5.Create())
{
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (Image image = Image.FromFile(fileName))
        {
            image.Save(stream, image.RawFormat);
            var hash = md5.ComputeHash(stream);
            var convertedHash = BitConverter.ToString(hash).Replace("-", String.Empty).ToLowerInvariant();
            return convertedHash;
        }
                        
    }
}
```

This seems very straightforward to me and the code runs without error, however no matter what image I feed into it, I get the same checksum, so something is wrong. I just can't seem to determine why this behavior is occurring. Any input or knowledge is greatly appreciated. Why does this generate the same checksum for any image? What am I doing wrong or missing?

(Edit: to be clear, I know that the image data itself must be exactly the same to generate the same checksum; this is what I need. i.e., I am not looking to find similar, or very similar images, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is caused by the fact that after writing to the stream, you do not reset the stream's position before reading it, so you get the same hash every single time.

You can easily verify this by passing in a new stream:

```
var hash = md5.ComputeHash(new MemoryStream());
var convertedHash = BitConverter.ToString(hash).Replace("-", String.Empty).ToLowerInvariant();
return convertedHash;
```

which for me returns `d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e` and is identical to what I get when loading files without rewinding the stream.

If you reset the position, you'll get different hashes per file as expected:

```
public string GetHashFromImage(string fileName)
{
    using (var md5 = MD5.Create())
    {
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (Image image = Image.FromFile(fileName))
            {
                image.Save(stream, image.RawFormat);
                
                stream.Position = 0;
                
                var hash = md5.ComputeHash(stream);
                var convertedHash = BitConverter.ToString(hash).Replace("-", String.Empty).ToLowerInvariant();
                return convertedHash;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This was exactly the problem, thank you! Peter also answered correctly but a moment after you. I am indeed now getting different hashes as expected so that makes me very happy. However, I have discovered that despite generating the hash from the image itself, changing the metadata of the file still produces different hashes. I will have to investigate further (I assume Image.PropertyItems is causing this), but regardless you got me yet one more step closer.

Comment: I don't want to go too far off topic, but wanted to comment and say that I did resolve the issue described in my previous comment. Loading an image into a Stream, then loading that into another Stream results in a raw image without any properties included. This raw image does produce the same hash between the same image even if two copies have different metadata attached.

Comment: @bodylice Glad to hear that this approach worked for you and that you solved the metadata problem!

Answer (score 2):

Try resetting the stream position to the start:

```
stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
```

Do this after `Save()` and before `ComputeHash()`.